# How do you set a session variable from the vm with Knockout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, session, knockout.js

I've seen a number of question on how to get a Session variable into knockout, but none explaining how to set one from a Knockout vm.  My setup:

-ASPX page where I get a Session["GridSize"] variable, and return it as a global variable called currentGridSize

-VM where I get that global variable, and set this.gridSize = globals.gridSize

-Dropdown that changes this.gridSize

What I need:

-Some way to set Session["GridSize"] = this.gridSize, either when it changes or when the page is left

I have tried:

-Using a webmethod function on my .aspx.vb and calling that (Session variables cannot be called from a Shared function, and webmethods must be shared)

-Calling <%Session["CurrentPageIndex"]= self.currentPageIndex();%> from the vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `Session` in an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, by doing the following to your page method:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession := True)> _
Public Shared Sub StoreSessionValue(sessionValue As String)
    ' Set a value into Session
    HttpContext.Current.Session("TheSessionValue") = sessionValue
End Sub

<WebMethod(EnableSession := True)> _
Public Shared Function GetSessionValue(sessionValueName As String) As String
    ' Get a value from Session
    Return HttpContext.Current.Session(sessionValueName)
End Sub
```

Note: You must fully qualify the `Session` object as `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

You can call this page method inside of your view model function, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "YourPage.aspx/GetSessionValue",
  data: "{'sessionValueName':'sessionValue'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    // Do something with data returned here

  }
});
```

Comment: Cool.  How do I call that from my vm, or from my aspx page via data-bind?  (The variable is stored in knockout, so I can't just assign the function to run onChange.)

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can use jQuery to call a page method.

Comment: No problem, glad you accepted the answer, feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)